# Mail.app automatically transforms links and email addresses when sending an email

Tags: mail.app

When I send an email using Mail.app, and I add some links or email addresses, it gets sent differently from how I saw it when sending it.

Compose window:

[image]

The email as sent:

[image]

How do I turn off this behavior? I don't see anything in the settings, and under Edit -> Substitutions the option "Smart Links" is unchecked. Also those options can only be changed while composing an email and always revery back whenever I compose a new email? Seems very buggy!

Comment: How do you add or paste the URL? Did you try paste as plain text?

Comment: If I paste the text into the email and send it, nothing happens. It's only when I type an enter or space at the end of the link and send the email that the transformation happens.